# Modernizr testing

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

How come this alerts both, yes and false?

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.cssgradients,
        yep: alert('Supports it!'),
        nope: alert('Oh, damn! This browser sucks!')
    }
]);
```

I'm using the latest chrome on OS X.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're calling `alert()` directly there, and the result from `alert()` (always `undefined`) is assigned to the `yep` and `nope` properties.  You need to wrap `alert()` in a function and assign that function instead:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.cssgradients,
        yep: function () { alert('Supports it!') },
        nope: function () { alert('Oh, damn! This browser sucks!') }
    }
]);
```

This *still* won't work because it's not how **yepnope** works.  `yep` and `nope` should be paths to JS files that are loaded:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.cssgradients,
        nope: 'cssgradients-shim.js'  //-> load a JS file to draw your gradients
    }
]);
```

As you discovered yourself, if you don't want to use the integrated yepnope.js, you can just use Modernizr *the traditional way*:

```
if (!Modernizr.cssgradients) {
    alert('Oh, damn! This browser sucks!');
}
```

Comment: You're right, solution is this: `if(Modernizr.rgba) { alert('boom'); }` add that to your answer and you get the green tick!

Answer (score 3):

With yepnope prefixes, it's possible to run predefined, named functions. Note: I have only tested this with latest chrome on OS X.

However, for this to work, you will need a "dummy URL", e.g., an image that you plan to load on the page (your logo is a good candidate).

Also, because `Modernizr.load` only aliases the `yepnope.apply` method, you will need to refer to `yepnope` by name to add a prefix.

```
/*globals window */
(function (Modernizr) {
    "use strict";
    window.yepnope.addPrefix('function', function (resourceObj) {
        var dummyUrl = 'static/my_logo.png';
        resourceObj.noexec = true;
        window[resourceObj.url]();
        resourceObj.url = dummyUrl;
        return resourceObj;
    });
    // predefined functions
    window.alert_support = function () {
        window.alert('Supports it!');
    };
    window.alert_damn = function () {
        window.alert('Oh, damn! This browser sucks!');
    };
    window.alert_boom = function () {
        window.alert('boom');
    };
    // Modernizer.load is an alias for yepnope. See API at http://yepnopejs.com/.
    Modernizr.load([{
        test: Modernizr.cssgradients,
        yep: 'function!alert_support',
        nope: 'function!alert_damn'
    }, {
        test: Modernizr.rgba,
        yep: 'function!alert_boom'
    }]);
}(window.Modernizr));
```

Of course, if you don't want to pollute the global `window` namespace, you could put your named functions in an object and change `window[resourceObj.url]();` to `window.MyObj[resourceObj.url]();`.

The real power of this is that `callback` functions fire, the named functions can call `Modernizr.load` as well, and/or you could write a more purposeful prefix than the generic function executor shown here.

Answer (score 2):

The `yep` and `nope` parameters do not accept functions as arguments. They should be a `string` or an `array of strings` indicating scripts to load based on whether the `test` succeeded or failed. See the documentation on [`Modernizr.load`](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load) for more information.