# Subtract code from app.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

To tackle some touch-related problems I have written a script in app.js to reopen and enhance the EventDispatcher. The script is pretty long and contaminates the normally so clean app.js.

So I'd like to have my script in a seperate file and than somehow be imported in app.js. What in your opinion is the best (cleanest) way to do this?

FYI I'm using Ember CLI

Answer (score 1):

I would place the script in file in in `public/assets/js` and load the script using `Modernizr.load` (Modernizr's implementation of [yes nope](http://yepnopejs.com/)) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7808643/2124849) inside of script tags just before the closing `body` tag of your `index.html` file. In this situation, you could use `Modernizr.touch` to detect for touch event support on the user's device and, if present, load the touch polyfill/script.

Alternatively, place the file in the same place and  load the script inside an if statement using `$.getScript(url)` in an initializer or the application view.

In both situations the script will not be imported into `app.js` but will still be loaded and ran.