# How to add date picker or any general jQuery plugin to Ember-CLI App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

So I am trying to add `pikaday` date picker to Ember-CLI app.

I've got the following in my `/app/views/calendar-view.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextView.extend({
    modelChangedValue: function(){
        console.log(this.get('value'));
    }.observes("value"),

    didInsertElement: function(){
        currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        formElement = this.$()[0];
        picker = new Pikaday({
            field: formElement,
            yearRange: [1900,currentYear+2]
        });
        this.set("_picker", picker);
  },

    willDestroyElement: function(){

        picker = this.get("_picker");

        if (picker) {
            picker.destroy();
        }

        this.set("_picker", null);
  }

});
```

My main issue is how to add the plugin itself into ember-cli?

This is the github link for pikaday: https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

More specifically I think this part might be important since Ember-CLI uses AMD: https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#amd-support

So how do I add the plugin itself to ember-cli?

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

Since writing this answer, the Ember Addon API has become more usable and are a perfect option if you're building an Ember component/mixin/other class that adds to the regular js plugin.

## Regular install

In a 'regular install' situation, you want the plugin to be available through your app and be included in the app's payload no matter what. To do this, add the file/package to your project's `vendor` directory. There are two immediately available ways to do this: use [Bower](http://bower.io/) or simply save a file or package in the directory.

**1) Bower**

Use Bower to install the package either through the terminal, like:

```
bower install ember-validations
```

Or, if there is no easy-install Bower package available, in your bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "dependencies": {
    "chosen": "https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.1.0/chosen_v1.1.0.zip"
  }
}
```

**2) Writing a file**

You don't have to use Bower to add files and directories to your `vendor` directory. You could create a file anywhere inside the `vendor` directory, copy and paste the plugins javascript into it and save it, and it will still be available to import into your app.

**3) Making it available in your app**

Regardless of the method through which you create and save the plugin scripts, you have to still have to import the file directly into your app. You do this in `Brocfile.js`. Add an import with the path to the file (main file if it's a bower installed package) just before `module.exports = app.toTree();`.

```
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/index.js');
app.import('vendor/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js');
```

There's more info in the [Managing Dependencies section of the ember-cli docs](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#asset-compilation).

## Polyfill or other non-essential plugins

There are some situation in which you don't want to always load/run a script in your app. For example, you are loading a large [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) only when the user is using IE. In this situation, you can create a directory in `public/assets` to hold the javascript files and load them using jQuery's `$.getScript()` method in an initializer or somewhere else within your Ember app.

I answered a similar question about that kind of scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699942/subtract-code-from-app-js/24700135#24700135).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it STILL WORKS!  And with fastboot, no less.  It's helpful when you just want to load a script for a single purpose in a component and you don't need it to be available to the app.  Plus you don't have to go thru the asset compilation nightmare.  Thanks!