# Ember.js date picker

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Is there any default date picker in Ember JS ? I see there is a date picker in Ember CLI, but I am not sure If I can use it or not.

Any help will be useful in this direction.

Comment: Why can’t you use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no default datepicker for Ember.js. However addon you are talking about - [Ember CLI Datepicker](https://github.com/gevious/ember-datepicker) works great. It uses [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) which supports following browsers:
[image: Pikaday comptaibility]

Usage of Ember CLI Datepicker is simple, you can use following code for creating datepicker for birthday:

```
{{date-picker date=model.birthday valueFormat='date' yearRange="-100, 0"}}
```

Installation is very simple if you use Ember CLI:

```
ember install:addon ember-cli-datepicker
```

If you are worried if you can use it with recent stable versions of Ember.js - the answer is yes. It works with latest version which is 1.9.1. You can, of course, use it with Ember Data too.

If you're not using Ember CLI, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728762/2166409) might be helpful.

Comment: Great this works for me, btw is there anyway to choose the time in the datepicker?