# Cannot include jQuery Table Sort

Tags: jquery, ember.js, semantic-ui

We are using Ember with Semantic-UI. We are trying to get a sortable table (https://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html#sortable).

We installed the kylefox jquery plugin with `npm install jquery-tablesort`

our .hbs file has the following included:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesort.js"></script> 
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('table').tablesort();
});
</script>
```

But I get the following in the console:

> jquery.js:3869 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesort is not a function

Is there anything we forgot to include?

Comment: Make sure `jquery.tablesort.js` file actually exists and path is correct.

Comment: We created a jquery.tablesort.js file which has the following code (https://semantic-ui.com/javascript/library/tablesort.js)
in the same directory as our .hbs file.¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Easiest way to test if browser see the directory is to open source code in browser and click on link for tablesort lib.

Comment: In the source code there is missing the jquery.tablesort.js indeed... However I placed it in my public, I placed it in the .hbs file, I imported it in the index.html but it is no recognized

Comment: What is .hbs file? If it is template, that does not mean that it is directly in root dir. In most cases it is not. Put `.js` file inside root www folder (where main `index.php` or any other root file is located.

Comment: Some resources to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727503/how-to-add-date-picker-or-any-general-jquery-plugin-to-ember-cli-app, https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code, https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/applications/initializers/

Answer (score 0):

First, read [ember-cli guide](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#javascript-assets). It explains how to manage dependencies and you doing it completely wrong.

Then read [ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/getting-started/core-concepts/) and try to understand how to use [components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code), because that's the only reliable way to use jquery plugins with ember.